# CDN suggestions for Wowza

Tags: cdn, wowza

Currently I am looking at different CDN networks to bring our site, VOD and the VOD content to a CDN based solution.

**Requirements:**

a) A Webserver (Apache, Mysql) (not necessarily) and

b) A Streaming Server (preferably Wowza), which has to have the VOD Content cloud-based,
meaning edge-oriented. (necessary!)

The reason I need Wowza is because it covers a very big spectrum of streams for end-devices,
and security, which we need. (and please don't suggest Amazon streaming, because it's flash)

The problem in general we had with amazon etc. is, that they do offer a good CDN network, but a) I didn't find their price strategic quite easy to see through, and b) - which is more important - they do not (!) offer to use Wowza on their cloud / edge oriented. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to me to use Wowza with Amazon.

My question is: Are there other good CDN networks (like edgecast etc.) that you can recommend? Akamai seems quite expensive. Edgecast I asked already (they'll come back to me yet).

I am happy for all answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edgecast doesn't offer Wowza streaming, but you may want to check with some of the folks listed at http://www.wowza.com/partners.

With Amazon, you're essentially rolling your own CDN by creating instances in different regions.

Answer (score 1):

try Amazon CloudFront. They say anything that serve with HTTP will work.

I'm running 3 Wowza boxes on AP region, and now running FMS + CLoudFront for my scalable livestreaming project.

Yet to test Wowza + CLoudFront

Answer (score 1):

Edgecast is FMS based, not wowza. 
[ScaleEngine is a wowza CDN](http://www.scaleengine.com/wowza-modules) (disclaimer, I work for ScaleEngine) - all the origins, and all the edges, are wowza. They can set anything in Application.xml you need, or install your custom module, or run a mid-origin setup from your single wowza server.

Comment: Stefan. I think it would be a good idea for you to take a look at erlyvideo, because it has many unique features: http://erlyvideo.org/comparison